# Windows 7 SP1 64 Bit file association

Tags: windows-7

Had Roxio and Nero both installed. Removed Roxio and left Nero 2018 in place.

I am trying to associate video file (.mp4 ; .mkv etc.) to open with Nero Media Home.

I go to the registry open with list and Nero media home is there but when I try to change defaults I get transferred to program files not program filesX86.

I scroll down to the x86 directory and add media home .exe but it will not stay.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing with the Registry, have you tried via the Control Panel.
Under "Associate a file type or protocol with a program" you can select the extension and then associate a program with it.  Clicking the "Change program" button allows you to browse to the folder where the .exe is.

Also, make sure you're selecting the correct .exe file.   If you double-click the .exe you want to associate, does it launch the program you're expecting?

Comment: Yes and it does not stay.

Comment: I also have Media Monkey Gold and I try to change to Nero Media Home and it goes to MM.I had it associated with VSO Media Player if Nero Media Home could not play .mkv files when watching on the home TV